# How may I call procedure inside another one in my PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a database in PostgreSQL, and I want to create procedure in which I'll add a new person to a table, but add may only, a person which have privilege status (which is of type `VARCHAR`) equals 'ADMIN' or 'OWNER'.

That's why my idea was to create procedure `addUser` and another procedure `addPrivilegeToUser` where I will calling `addUser`. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly, I've got error message

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "CALL".

Here is some code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addUser(loginUserToAdd VARCHAR(30), 
loginUser VARCHAR(30), accessTypeT VARCHAR(20))
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
 INSERT INTO privilege(userId, storageId, accessType) 
 VALUES((SELECT userID
        FROM userTable                                                               
        WHERE(login = loginUserToAdd)), 

        (SELECT storageId                                                                                    
         FROM privilege                                                                                    
         WHERE userId = (SELECT userId                                                                     
                         FROM userTable                                                                                                     
                         WHERE login = loginUser)), accessTypeT);
$$;


CREATE PROCEDURE addUserToStorage(loginUserToAdd VARCHAR(30), 
loginUser VARCHAR(30), accessTypeT VARCHAR(20))
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT privilege.accessType, usertable.login, CASE privilege.accessType 
    WHEN ('OWNER' OR 'ADMIN')
     THEN
        CALL addUser(loginUserToAdd, loginUser, accessTypeT)
     END
 FROM privilege
 INNER JOIN userTable ON privilege.userId = usertable.userId
 WHERE (userTable.login = loginUser);
  END
$$;
```

Comment: I doubt you can call a procedure from a `SELECT` statement. Try to rework the `addUserToStorage` procedure using PL/pgSQL with an `IF` checking for the existence of an appropriate record using `EXISTS` and call the procedure in the affirmative branch of that `IF`.

Comment: It's not that you can't call a proc from another proc. The issue is that you can't call a proc from a SELECT statement.

Comment: @Parfait not exactly cause I want to ```INSERT``` if in column of another table is ```'ADMIN' OR 'OWNER'``` thats why I don't think will be possible to do only using conditional ```INSERT``` or conditional ```SELECT```.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addUserToStorage` is procedural in nature, so it should be written with the [`plpgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) language rather than `sql` (PL=Procedural Language).

`plpgsql` allows control flow with variables, conditions and loops around SQL statements. The `CALL` statements should be in an `IF ... THEN CALL addUser(...); END IF;` block.

Answer (score 0):

I also add that I've tried to do it creating only one procedure with `IF` statement like below and there was ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF".

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addUserToStorage1(loginUserToAdd VARCHAR(30), loginUser VARCHAR(30), accessTypeT VARCHAR(20))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
IF EXISTS(SELECT privilege.accessType, usertable.login
          FROM privilege
          INNER JOIN userTable ON privilege.userId = usertable.userId
          WHERE ((usertable.login = loginUser) AND (privilege.accessType = 'OWNER' 
                    OR privilege.accessType = 'ADMIN')))

    THEN
        INSERT INTO privilege(userId, storageId, accessType) 
     VALUES(loginUserToAdd, (SELECT storageId                                                                                    
                             FROM privilege                                                                                     
                             WHERE userId = (SELECT userId                                                                                                     
                                             FROM userTable                                                                                                     
                                             WHERE login = loginUser)), accessTypeT);
    END IF;

$$;
```